# disable textBox ability to display old data typed in it

Tags: c#, asp.net

When user start typing in their username in textBox field, a dropdown list shows old data. How can I clear this?. It's a class room and many students logs in from the same pc everyday, I don't want the student to see his mates usernames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's an asp.net TextBox control you can also set its [AutoCompleteType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype.aspx) property to `Disabled`.

Answer (score 3):

Add this attribute to the textbox:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Comment: This works. But remember it's a non standard attribute and breaks HTML validation.